# Trouble Shooting Google OAuth 2.0 - Incorrect Query Separator from Google's Servers

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

**login.php**

```
<?php
    define('client_id', 'cid');
    define('redirect_uri', 'http://domain.tld/file.php');
    define('client_secret', 'secret');


    $endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    $querystr = array(
        'response_type' => 'token',
        'client_id' => client_id,
        'redirect_uri' => redirect_uri,
        'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
#       'state' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );


    if (isset($_GET['access_token']))
        print_r($_GET);
    else
        header('Location: ' . $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($querystr));

?>
```

The above code works fine, the problem I'm having is that the responce I'm getting from Google is not well formed. The query string that I'm getting from them does not start with a question mark `?`, it starts with a number sign `#`. The following is an example returend from Google's server.

`http://domain.tld/file.php#access_token=ya29.AHES6ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmno&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

Why is it separating the query string from the file path by a number sign? It it because I'm not using a https schema and it's punishing me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's called the "hash" of the URL. For responses from the server to the client (and *not* vice versa), this is a common scheme. Facebook OAuth 2.0 also uses this technique, for example. Just get used to it, and interpret the response beginning from the hash sign.

Comment: I changed the responce_type to code and got a normal query string. Thank you for the help! I had no idea this was normal. Can you add some detail on why they use a hash of the URL?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason; I guess the ? more indicates query towards the server.